# Derivation of equation form of 1st law of Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

The 1st law of Thermodynamics can be stated in differential form (without chemical potentials):$$dU=T\cdot dS -p\cdot dV$$
If we integrate the above relation we get $$\int du= \int TdS-\int PdV \Rightarrow$$ $$U=T\cdot S-P\cdot V$$
What bothers me is that in general if we have a differential of a function $f(x,y)$: $$df=P(x,y)dx + Q(x,y)dy \Rightarrow$$ it isnt't necessarily true that:$$\int df = \int Pdx + \int Qdy$$ Any ideas?

Comment: What’s the basis of your third equation if you don’t know the functions $T(S)$ and $P(V)$?

Comment: Suppose that both T and P are constants. Then we should get the third equation. My problem is that this method doesn't work in general for functions.

Comment: If temperature and presure are constant then for a closed system $V$ too is constant (for ideal gas). This means $\Delta U =0$

Comment: Also your indefinite integral does not cotain integration constant.

Comment: If T and P are constant, then everything else is constant too.

Answer (score 2):

Without the explicit indication of the functions involved in thermodynamic formulas, it is easy to misunderstand their meaning.

Differential form for energy. The general formula is
$$
dU = T(S,V)dS - P(S,V)dV,
$$
where, being $dU$ an exact differential, the functions $T(S,V)$ and $-P(S,V)$ should be intended as partial derivatives of $U(S,V)$ with respect $S$, the former, and with respect $V$, the latter.

It is clear that in general, without the explicit form of $T(S,V)$ and $-P(S,V)$, it is impossible to integrate a differential form.

However, in the case of internal energy (or other thermodynamic potentials) there is the possibility of a shortcut if these functions are extensive, aka homogeneous functions of degree one of their variables. In such a case, Euler's theorem implies
$$
U(S,V)= T(S,V)S - P(S,V)V.
$$
Therefore in this case, knowledge of the two functions $T(S,V)$ and $-P(S,V)$ is equivalent to integrate the differential form.

Comment: So applying integration to both sides is only equivalent when the function is homogeneous?

Comment: @adosar The key point is that you do not have freedom to chose $T$ and $P$ independently on $S$ and $V$.  $T$ and $P$ in the differential expression of the first principle  are always functions of $S$ and $V$ (each of them).

Comment: Consider the function $f(x,y)=xy$. Then, the differential is:$$df=P(x,y)dx + Q(x,y)dx=ydx + xdy$$ If I integrate both parts I get that $f(x,y)= 2xy + C$ and $P,Q$ are functions of $(x,y)$ as $T,P$ are functions of $(P,V)$

Comment: @adosar the function in your example is not homogeneous of degree one. Use $f(x,y)=(xy)^\frac12$ instead.

Comment: So we can get back the function with integration of differential if the function is homogeneous of degree one?

Comment: @adosar if the differential is exact, integrating the diffrential form will give always the primitive. What is special with homogenous  functions of degree one is that the primitive can be obtained at once, just as $f(x,y)=P(x,y)x+Q(x,y)y$.

Comment: @adosar Just to be more explicit, in no way one can say that the above $f(x,y)$ is obtained integrating only the factors $dx$ and $dy$. That would be a mathematical nonsense

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104376/discussion-between-ado-sar-and-giorgiop).

Answer (score 1):

The method does not hold in general because there are additional requirements on $U$, $S$ and $V$ that makes your second equation always valid. First, the differential form $dU$ defines $T$ and $P$ as derivatives of $U$:
$$
T = \left ( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right )_V, \quad P = -\left ( \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \right )_S .
$$

Secondly, $U$, $S$ and $V$ are all *extensive parameters* (meaning that if you scale your system all these parameters scale in the same way), and this requirement leads to $U(S,V)$ being an *homogeneous function of degree 1* in $S$ and $V$. To put it in math form, for any $\lambda >0$, our function $U$ satisfies
$$
U(\lambda S, \lambda V) = \lambda U(S,V). \tag{*}
$$

Just the requirement of $U$ being an homogeneous function of its variables is enough to allow you to integrate your second equation just like you did (even if $P$ and $T$ are functions of $S$ and $V$). Start by taking the derivative of both sides of $(*)$ with respect to $\lambda$ in order to arrive at
$$
S \left ( \frac{\partial U}{\partial (\lambda S)} \right )_{\lambda V} + V \left ( \frac{\partial U}{\partial (\lambda V)} \right )_{\lambda S} = U(S, V)
$$
where the chain rule of partial derivatives was used. Since this is valid for any $\lambda > 0$, we pick $\lambda = 1$ and substitute the definitions of $P$ and $T$:
$$
 U = TS - PV.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I did to derive the equation. But our proffesor integrated both sides.

Comment: @adosar actually one must carefully apply integration to a differential like that. If you just integrate $T \,dS$ and $P \, dV$ at face value you may get the wrong result for $U$ because the first integration has as an additive "constant" $f(V)$ while the second has a constant $g(S)$. You'll then have to compare $\partial U/\partial V$ to $P$ in order to find what $f(V)$ is (and analogous for $g(S)$). I'd say integration of such a differential is not that straightforward and should be understood as "symbolic integration"